# Annhilating polynomials for $T:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ with 1 as the only eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ be a linear transformation for $n\ge 2$ . Suppose $1$ is the only eigen value of $T$ . Which of the following statements are true?

$(a) T^k\ne I$,for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$

$(b)(T-I)^{n-1}=0$

$(c)(T-I)^n=0$

$(d) (T-I)^{n+1}=0$

My attempts

$(a)$ is false by taking $T=I$

For $(c)$ and $(d)$ ,

The underlying feild is algebraically closed so the minimal polynomial is product of linear factors i.e $(x-1)^k$ where $1\le k \le n$ while the characteristics polynomial is $(x-1)^n$ and so $(c)$ and $(d)$ are true.

Assiming $(b)$ is false, I need help finding counter eg. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b) take the single Jordan block:
$$\pmatrix{1\\1&1\\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ & & 1&1}$$